# Can't get correct response using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a code that automatically adds items into the shopping cart

Here is the screen shot after I pressed the 'add to cart' bottom
[image: after clicking 'add to cart']

#### My code:

```py
import requests                                                       
import time                                                           
t = int(round((time.time())*1000))
session = requests.session()
get =session.get('https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DGBJAF-A900962EG?fq=/S/DGCV0M')
cookies = get.cookies.get_dict()                                      
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82
Safari/537.36'}
snap_up = session.get(f'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/cart/v1/prod/DGBJAFA900962EG-000/snapup?_{t}',headers=headers, cookies=cookies)                        
print(snap_up.text)
```

this request should get a response like this (viewed in DevTools,Network in chrome):

```json
{"Expire":15,"Status":"OK","MACExpire":"2021\/09\/21 20:21:07","MAC":"f7cfcd2"}
```

however, I got

```json
{"Expire":15,"Status":"ProdLocked","MACExpire":"","MAC":""}
```

Can anybody help me to solve this? I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Please use proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make your question easy to read & answerable.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you "viewed in DevTools,Network in chrome" ? Maybe the request had some special headers like[`Accept: application/json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept).

Comment: I am not allowed to post an image directly so it becomes a line, and yes, there is 'Accept: application/json' in the request header.

Comment: Posting an image (embedded) is explained in [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), section __Images__. In your case this markdown is allowed: `![after clicking 'add to cart'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPtZ5.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing your GET request

To make your GET request work same as in the browser, you need to set some request-headers. See the curl command, copied from browser's Network tab:

```sh
curl 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/cart/v1/prod/DGBJAF-A900962EG-000/snapup?_=1632285660820'\
 -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0'\
 -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'\
 -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'\
 --compressed\
 -H 'Referer: https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DGBJAF-A900962EG?fq=/S/DGCV0M'\
 -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'\
 -H 'Connection: keep-alive'\
 -H 'Cookie: ECC=e66160898a790f09da3ec9c2abfe97da519c81af.1632285509; venguid=fd6d2088-7179-447f-8f7b-f4139bf914f8.wgc-7l7c20210922; vensession=955841cd-8920-4952-9b06-dfd7f201f085.wgc-1w1g20210922.se; uuid=xxx-3736b290-822d-41fe-9127-7e93c02b839e; puuid=K.20210922123847.0; U=3e04245bd80981fb53ed5d9b310835de45f63c2b; ECWEBSESS=cd4e358826.eebc03d8efde55c3591e6ba2832582ae63a3f66e.1632285644; HistoryEC=%7B%22P%22%3A%5B%7B%22Id%22%3A%22DGBJAF-A900962EG%22%2C%20%22M%22%3A1632285645%7D%5D%2C%20%22T%22%3A1%7D; _CART_TM_COOKIE=e66160898a790f09da3ec9c2abfe97da519c81af.1632285509; PCHOMEUNIQID=3a01a5be33347fb29d85542b1f6aba0b'\
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty'\
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors'\
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-GPC: 1'
```

Here particularly the **cookie** header ( `-H 'Cookie:`) will transfer your session state. With above request, you will get a valid `MAC` in the JSON response:

```json
{"Expire":15,"Status":"OK","MACExpire":"2021\/09\/22 12:44:01","MAC":"6b4df23"}
```

The `MAC` related response data you will use next to add an item.

### Adding items to a shopping cart

In your case ("adding items to a shopping cart") there is more to do than simply:

```
GET https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/cart/v1/prod/DGBJAFA900962EG-000/snapup?_{t}
```

#### Look for POST or PUT requests

Creating or adding via REST is usually done by HTTP methods `POST` or `PUT`.
Look for all requests in your DevTool's "Network" tab after the click:

- insert
- modify

For example the **modify** POST:

```sh
curl 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/fscart/index.php/prod/modify?callback=jsonp_addcart&1632285662019' -X POST -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 () Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0' -H 'Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DGBJAF-A900962EG?fq=/S/DGCV0M' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Origin: https://24h.pchome.com.tw' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: ECC=e66160898a790f09da3ec9c2abfe97da519c81af.1632285509; venguid=fd6d2088-7179-447f-8f7b-f4139bf914f8.wgc-7l7c20210922; vensession=955841cd-8920-4952-9b06-dfd7f201f085.wgc-1w1g20210922.se; uuid=xxx-3736b290-822d-41fe-9127-7e93c02b839e; puuid=K.20210922123847.0; U=3e04245bd80981fb53ed5d9b310835de45f63c2b; ECWEBSESS=cd4e358826.eebc03d8efde55c3591e6ba2832582ae63a3f66e.1632285644; HistoryEC=%7B%22P%22%3A%5B%7B%22Id%22%3A%22DGBJAF-A900962EG%22%2C%20%22M%22%3A1632285645%7D%5D%2C%20%22T%22%3A1%7D; _CART_TM_COOKIE=e66160898a790f09da3ec9c2abfe97da519c81af.1632285509; PCHOMEUNIQID=3a01a5be33347fb29d85542b1f6aba0b' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-GPC: 1' -H 'TE: trailers' --data-raw 'data=%7B%22G%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22A%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22B%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22TB%22%3A%2224H%22%2C%22TP%22%3A2%2C%22T%22%3A%22ADD%22%2C%22TI%22%3A%22DGBJAF-A900962EG-000%22%2C%22RS%22%3A%22DGCV0M%22%2C%22YTQ%22%3A1%2C%22CAX%22%3A%226b4df23%22%2C%22CAXE%22%3A%222021%2F09%2F22%2012%3A44%3A01%22%7D'
```

#### Reproducing the request

The order-data:

- product `\"TI\":\"DGBJAF-A900962EG-000\"`
- quantity `\"YTQ\":1`
- cart-action `\"T\":\"ADD\"`
- your session-based cart- or transaction-id `\"CAX\":\"6b4df23\"` (see "MAC" from previous request) and expiry `\"CAXE\":\"2021/09/22 12:44:01\"` (probably "MACExpire" from previous request)

is posted as with request-header `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

```
"{\"G\":[],\"A\":[],\"B\":[],\"TB\":\"24H\",\"TP\":2,\"T\":\"ADD\",\"TI\":\"DGBJAF-A900962EG-000\",\"RS\":\"DGCV0M\",\"YTQ\":1,\"CAX\":\"6b4df23\",\"CAXE\":\"2021/09/22 12:44:01\"}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have successfully get a valid "MAC" and "MACExpire" for the followed code.
However, after looked for  all requests (despite those from facebook or google) in DevTool's "Network" tab after the click, and added them into my code in chronological order, I still can't put item in the shopping cart with it, all the requests return status_code = 200, and again I'm confused where is the mistake.

Comment: @k19950907 Even an erroneous or "negative" response can have HTTP code 200 (see your failed MAC queries) - the response body needs to be examined. I can try to investigate, although this would actually be a new question  Meanwhile please read [How to thank on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: my code ends up with the modify POST, in which I copied the headers fron DevTools, and the Form data was build into a dictionary, and then transformed to urlencode form when I posted the request

Comment: In additional, I found that the response of the modify POST is

```try{jsonp_addcart({"PRODTOTAL":1790,"PRODCOUNT":1,"TYPE":"BIGCAR","PRODADD":"1","ISSALEOUT":0,"OverQtyMsg":""});}catch(e){if(window.console){console.log(e);}}
```
when the item is already in the cart. 

On the other hand, if the cart is empty, the response is 
```try{jsonp_addcart({"PRODTOTAL":0,"PRODCOUNT":0,"TYPE":"BIGCAR","PRODADD":"1","ISSALEOUT":0,"OverQtyMsg":""});}catch(e){if(window.console){console.log(e);}}
```